# Copying Databrick Databricks Hive-MetaStore to Azure SQL DB Delay

Tags: azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-databricks

I am copying data from Databrick Hive-MetaStore to Azure SQL DB using simple JDBC connector. The number of rows is just over 1 million rows. However, it appears to be taking an inordinate amount of time ... its been stuck copying for over 30mins (and still no data copied over)

The code to copy is:

```
product = spark.sql("select * from master.product")
df = product
schema = 'dbo'
entityName = 'product'
l_schemas=[schema]# list for storing schemas
l_tables=[entityName] # list for storing respective tables in the particular indexed schema
for i in range(0,len(l_schemas)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    df.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

The capacity of the Azure SQLDB is as follows:

[image]

Can someone let me know if my code is causing some kind of bottleneck? If I limit the number of rows to 1000 it copies straight away.

I don't think it's the SQLDB, but I could be wrong.

Any thoughts?

By way of an update:

I have just downloaded the table to my desktop - the table is 212Gb.
[image]

New update.
I've updated the compute the following, and its still taking forever
[image]

New update.

I have updated the compute to 200 DTUs
[image]

And now the transfer is stuck half-way through
[image]

Would this suggest I need to increase the compute further?

Comment: I think 100 DTU is a little low for this amount of data. You can check in Azure portal for this DB under overview->key matrics how much of the DTU the server is using. If its on 100% all the time then you need more resources on the SQL server side.

Comment: @ChenHirsh, that is what I thought, so I updated the question with the new compute,  and its still taking forever

Comment: I think you changed the data max size and not the DTU (which is CPU+memory).

Comment: I thought the issue was max size. ok, I'll try changing the DTUs.

Comment: I have updated the question showing the new compute. Would you suggest I need to increase the compute further?

Comment: Check the metrics on the Azure SQL database to see if it's using all the DTUs (100 %)